# find function returning undefined from API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, fetch-api

I have a function that passes in an ID that fetches a API that doesn't support searching by certain IDs, so I'm trying to build a find function that searches for the ID and returns it.

I've made this work before but I was moving functions around to their own files and it seems passing the value in possibly has broke the function? I'm not getting any errors from the function but maybe I'm writing the find function incorrectly?

```
import React from 'react'

export const fetchHeroDetail = async (id) => {
    const data = await fetch(`https://api.opendota.com/api/heroStats`)
    const heroDetails = await data.json()
    console.log(id)
    console.log(heroDetails)
    console.log(heroDetails.find(heroDetail => id === heroDetail.id))
    return heroDetails.find(heroDetail => id === heroDetail.id)


};
```

Comment: I don't see anything inherently wrong there, however, it should be easy to pinpoint the problem by looking at the result of `console.log(id)` and `console.log(heroDetails)`.

Comment: Both spit out what was thought to be. id = whatever hero i've clicked on and heroDetails returns the full object of heroes

Answer (score 0):

so basically all I needed to do was convert the id into a number from a string. I just completed that by doing

```
return heroDetails.find(heroDetail => heroDetail.id === +id)
```